# Floating image to the left of Bootstrap 3 column fluid row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to float a little image of a cloud to the left of a 3 column fluid row (Bootstrap). Here is my code:

```
      <img src="img/cloud1.png" style="width:100px;float:left;">
      <div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top:50px;">
  <div class="span4 hero-unit" style="min-height:400px;background-color:#FFCFD9;">
    <h3>Quick Links</h3>
    <p><a href="mailto:info@albancloud.com" style="text-decoration:underline;">Our Email : info@albancloud.com</a>
    </p>
    <p><a href="pricing.php" style="text-decoration:underline;">Pricing options</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="span4 hero-unit" style="min-height:400px;background-color:#CAF9FC;">
    <h3>What We Do</h3>
    <p>albanCloud provides security and flexability to your Business’s IT. We provide our clients with a fully managed service for their cloud backups and virtual servers.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="span4 hero-unit" style="min-height:400px;background-color:#FCF6A2;">
    <h3>Where We Operate</h3>
    <p>
      Hertfordshire area, St Albans, Luton, Harpenden, Hatfield, Hemel, Welyn, Watford, Harrow, Barnet.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've made sure that the span class numbers add up to 12 but I don't know how to take into account floating images within the scaffolding system.

**Ideally I'd like the cloud to sit on the top right hand corner of the left most hero unit ("Quick Links")**

This is the current result:

[image: current situation]

I need for the third hero-unit to fit on the same row - I've tried putting the img outside of the `row-fluid` div, as well as using `inline-block` and block and also negative margins

P.S I am open to alternatives to float as I want this to be responsive

Note: I haven't specified any more stylings than the inline CSS given in the example above, the rest is just default Bootstrap

Comment: your code is very difficult to read, please show it neatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your image inside the first box and then position it:

```
<div class="row-fluid quick-links" style="margin-top:50px;">
  <div class="span4 hero-unit" style="padding:20px;min-height:400px;background-color:#FFCFD9;">
  <img src="img/cloud1.png" class="cloud" >
  <h3>Quick Links</h3>
  <p><a href="mailto:info@albancloud.com" style="text-decoration:underline;">Our Email : info@albancloud.com</a></p>
  <p><a href="pricing.php" style="text-decoration:underline;">Pricing options</a></p>
  </div>
...
</div>

.quick-links {
  position: relative;
end

.cloud {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px; # Maybe you should update this value.
  left: 0px; # Maybe you should update this value.
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very helpful thank you, both are great answers just different solutions.